# Application on server crashes when accessed via browser - after full system upgrade

Tags: arch-linux

After a recent full-system upgrade one of my applications stopped working. It's Fatrat 1.2.0_beta2-11 on Archlinux (installed from community repository).

Without enabling web access the application works just fine, but when web access is enabled **and accessed via browser**, the app on server crashes:

```
[pi@raspberrypi data]$ fatrat -n
Current locale "C"
Locating the Java VM for Java-based plugins...
Loading queues
HttpService::applySettings()
Listening on port 2233
FatRat is up and running now
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I tried downgrading the application to beta2_10 from cache but it didn't help. I also cleared all fatrat .conf files and reinstalled to the latest version, it didn't help either so I suspect there must be a problem with some upgraded dependency.

How can I check the fatrat dumped core? Or what else I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### More logging

Given it's a Java application there should be a stack trace that the JVM dumped along with this error. Is there a log file that `fatrat` is generating? You might need to specify this via switches when you run he above command to get access to this log file or the stack trace.

#### libtorrent changed?

Also looking through the [FAQ for `fatrat`](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/faq) there is this bullet:

> Q: I have installed a new version of libtorrent and FatRat doesn't download anything and/or crashes. Fix it!
>
> A: Please recompile FatRat against the newly installed libtorrent before reporting bugs. Libtorrent's API/ABI tends to change frequently and even between minor versions.

#### Getting more information

Anytime I run into an issue such as this I almost always put an `strace` in front of it so that I can get some insight into what libraries and system calls an application is making. This usually gives you good leads to follow when chasing down problems such as this.

```
$ strace -o fatrat_strace.log fatrat -n
```

After it dies you should have a complete transcript of what the application was doing from the time you invoked it until the coredump.

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert so after a few hours of tries I just reverted to a month-old backup. But thanks for the `strace` tip, I'll definitely use it also in the future!